# Interpolation of missing values using results produced by arima

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation

I would like to know if anyone knows how to apply the `arima` results to calculate missing values in the observation period.  I am looking for something similar to `forecast.arima()`, that forecasts values based on `arima` results.

Does anyone has experiences in using data from other sources that are complete but with less accuracy, to replace the missing values? Is it feasible to decompose both datasets using `stl` and recalculate the new values using the observation data?

I am using daily climatic observations for a large number of years, although some of the missing data is between observations, I have also large periods of time without any observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Box and Jenkins](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470272848) all the way back in the first edition of their book (1970) proposed backcasting as a way to "fill in" missing values in the middle of a time series.  The link I gave is for the most recent 2008 edition.